# How to use ng-show on Kendo Grid ?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have condition for ng-show if json response ratingStatusKey = RA_RT_EDITABLE show edit button. how i can achieve this using angularjs.
So far i tried this..

grid.js

```
template: '<a  href="" ng-click=\'editProcessRtng(this.dataItem)\'>`<span ng-show="{{ratingStatusKey}}!==RA_RT_EDITABLE" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the mustaches from `ng-show`.

`ng-show="ratingStatusKey!==RA_RT_EDITABLE"`

You shouldn't use them in angular directives - only in regular DOM attributes. Also make sure `RA_RT_EDITABLE` is defined in the global scope otherwise the comparison will fail.

Comment: I used your answer and implement this if($rootScope.ratingStatusKey === RA_RT_EDITABLE){
        return true;
    }

Comment: Its hiding on all rows even where status is non editable